# Warning 1072 in MySql - Key column 'name' doesn't exist in table`

Tags: mysql, sql, warnings

Getting the warning `0 row(s) affected, 1 warning(s):
1072 Key column 'name' doesn't exist in table` And I do not know what it means. Does anybody have an explaination?

The table/SP is as follows

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `sectors`
(
  `id`        INT(10) UNSIGNED   NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `sector`    VARCHAR(25)        NOT NULL ,
                                                                           --
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`) ,
  UNIQUE  INDEX `sector_idx` USING BTREE (`sector` ASC)
);
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `AddSector` (IN sector VARCHAR(25),
                              OUT result BOOLEAN)
  MODIFIES SQL DATA
BEGIN
  DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLWARNING, SQLEXCEPTION SET result = FALSE;
  SET result = TRUE;
                                                                           --
  INSERT INTO `sectors` (`sector`) VALUES (sector);
  COMMIT;
END $$
```

Comment: https://www.vbulletin.com/forum/showthread.php/21575-Error-1072-Key-column-userid-doesn-t-exist-in-table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the procedure to:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE `AddSector` (IN pSector VARCHAR(25),  <<-- fix nameclash here
                              OUT result BOOLEAN)
  MODIFIES SQL DATA
BEGIN
  DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLWARNING, SQLEXCEPTION SET result = FALSE;
  SET result = TRUE;

  INSERT INTO `sectors` (`sector`) VALUES (pSector);  <<-- and here
  --  COMMIT;  <<-- You don't need a commit.
END $$
```

All stuff inside a stored proc is already run inside an implicit transaction, so the commit is not needed, and may actually be an error *(not sure)*.
    DELIMITER ;